# How to scroll xx pixels or % at once

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, transition

I am building a website and I want to customize the scrolling. If the user scrolls I want them to scroll down 100% at once like in this website: http://onlinedepartment.nl/

EDIT: I already managed smooth scrolling with anchor points. But I want it to work on mousescroll too

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That website was pretty nice.
There's kind of alot of stuff to keep in mind to do this. 
Here's a demo of all the things i describe below ([fiddle](http://codepen.io/Hatlen/pen/stubk)).

1. Every "page's" height is as high as `window.innerHeight - /* the height of the menu */`
2. Every time you scroll you'll have to check if you scroll upwards or downwards <del>you can do that by updating a variable on every scroll event with the `window.pageYOffset` value and check if the new value is higher or lower than this, if it's higher you're scrolling downwards</del>. If `event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY > 0` you're scrolling upwards. Event is the scroll event.
3. Then on every down(up)scroll you'll want to scroll one page's height down or up. You can have a variable save which page you're on or you can see how many pages the current window.pageYOffset corresponds to. To scroll you do `$('body').animate({scrollTop: /*page height*/ * /* the page number - 1 (to get it zero based) */})`
4. Then you'll not want to scroll more than one page every time you use the scrollwheel. So then you could set e.g. a blocked variable to true (`blocked = true`) when you scroll and after a timeout you reset it to false `setTimeout(function() { blocked = false; })` and every time you scroll you check if the variable is `blocked === false` and then you do the scrolling otherwise you do nothing `event.preventDefault()` in the function bound to the scroll event.

There's probably more stuff to consider but...

You probably know this but to attach an event handler to the scroll event:
`$(document).on('scroll', function() { /*the code that should be run on the scroll event */})`

EDIT: you had to bind to the mousewheel event instead of the scroll event to be able to prevent the page from scrolling with `event.preventDefault()` inside the function listening to the event.

EDIT2: Here's a demo http://codepen.io/Hatlen/pen/stubk.
One thing that did not work with codepen was that the window.innerHeight was not correct so the div's heights is not the same as the real window.innerHeight.

EDIT3: Instead of saving the window.pageYOffset and comparing the new offset with that you could get the direction from the scroll event `event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY`